# Postgres COUNT(*) abnormally slow

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `entries` which has 176 million rows, each row consists of an average ~3kb of text data.

`id | text1 | text2 | text3| etc..`

There's only 1 index on the primary key (id).

Running a simple count:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM entries
```

Takes **12 minutes** to finish. Even though count(*) on another 1M row table in the same database takes only **60ms**.

Here's `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` of the count query.

```
                                                                      QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=32009352.88..32009352.89 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=754712.245..754713.448 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=320 read=31087918
   I/O Timings: read=2177605.284
   ->  Gather  (cost=32009352.67..32009352.88 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=754711.927..754713.441 rows=3 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         Buffers: shared hit=320 read=31087918
         I/O Timings: read=2177605.284
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=32008352.67..32008352.68 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=754709.490..754709.491 rows=1 loops=3)
               Buffers: shared hit=320 read=31087918
               I/O Timings: read=2177605.284
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on entries  (cost=0.00..31824329.73 rows=73609173 width=0) (actual time=1.485..749697.882 rows=58983879 loops=3)
                     Buffers: shared hit=320 read=31087918
                     I/O Timings: read=2177605.284
 Planning Time: 0.067 ms
 Execution Time: 754713.485 ms
(16 rows)
```

I understand that count(*) is relatively slow, but I'm puzzled as to why this particular table is extremely slower relative to others, not only when counting but also it takes more than 3 hours to add a new column and insert data to it.

Does the size of data in each row hamper a count query?

Environment:

- Machine: AWS RDS Graviton2 (8gb ram, 2cpu)
- Postgresql 14 (same issue on 13 too)
- `work_mem` set at 100mb

Comment: I'm not sure why's that but is `count(1)` any faster?

Comment: @haba713 It takes just as long actually

Comment: @haba713: no, `count(1)` is actually slightly slower. There is no database where `count(1)` is faster - it's an urban myth that never was true.

Comment: The table is over 237GB, and that takes a while. Is there a primary key you can use for the count? SELECT COUNT(id) FROM entries;

Comment: Reading 31087918 blocks means it's reading roughly 237GB from disk. With the timing information that's a read performance of about 110MB per second which seems rather slow to me. Is that somehow an I/O limited instance (e.g. cloud service)?

Comment: VACUUM the table.